# Install Alpine Linux in a specific partition

Tags: linux, terminal, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install Alpine Linux for a school project.
I ran through the setup-alpine procedure without installing it for a couple times to familiarize myself with the procedure.
However there is a point where I still have doubts, that is how to install alpine to a specific partition without running the rick of it erasing the whole HD.
The setup-alpine only offers the option to install on sda.
I read the wiki about manuall selecting a partition, which mention using setup-disk, but I'm not not clear if i have to run setup-disk BEFORE setup-alpine of INSTEAD of setup-alpine.
I have already set up the partition where to install Alpine /dev/sda6.
Also the wiki says setup-disk would automatically create a /boot and swap partition within the volume where it installs the system, which i don't want since 0 have already a swap partition on the HD.

So, my question is:

How do I proceed to install Alpine on /dev/sda6 without:
1) messing the whole HD
2) installing a bootloader in MBR
3) creating a swap partition anywhere
4) possibly without creating a separate /boot partition in the volume where it install the system (because i read booting Alpine with Grub from another install gets tricky)

Note: I ask this question here because: a) Alpine forum has been disabled b) guys on their IRC channel doesn't answer c) their website suggest to ask questions here.

Comment: Why not use a virtual machine instead?

Comment: The purpose of the school project is to create an installed minimal system.

Comment: VMs and real hardware are pretty much the same thing. Unless your assignment is *about* installing it besides another OS I wouldn't risk busting up my system for it.

Comment: Well, yes, the idea is to learn how to do it. I'm sure it's possible (any Linux system can be installed on any partition). In the Alpine wiki, the previous installer was more explicit about this, whereas the new one, trying to automatize the process, is not so clear as to the procedure. At least to me.

Comment: You could first setup an ubuntu on the vm, then take a snapshot, then try to setup alpine on an additional partition. If something goes wrong you just would reload the snapshot. Much easier workflow for experiments like that. Can't help you on alpine question itself however, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion anyway. This is something an Alpine user should help me with.

Comment: Prepare partitions as you like, format them, mount rootfs somewhere, run setup-disk (instead of setup-alpine) with path of the rootfs mount point instead of dev. I'll write more details as an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Actually i followed the wiki found at https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installing_Alpine_on_HDD_dualbooting

Comment: I was able to install the system and boot it. Now at boot I get the error Mounting /dev/sda6 on /sysroot failed: no such file or directory. I assume some parameter is missing because I have seen the topic comes up often in Alpine bugs reports, but havent had the time to figure out why it happened to this install yet. Any suggestions as what may cause the sysroot error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
I found pretty much all I needed to know in the Wiki at:

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installing_Alpine_on_HDD_dualbooting

The problem was that the main installation Wiki was a bit terse on the topic and I'm unfamiliar with Alpine procedures.
Also, the sysroot system  error at boot was due to a my own mistake, a misplaced digit coping the blkid UUID datas in the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file. Alpine is not difficult to install in dual booting, it only takes a bit of extra attention to details.